# How to Call a PHP on the Click of a Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am a newbie in **PHP**.

I need to run this *jQuery code* to *PHP*.

`Class active` just change `display:none` to `display:block`

The code is here http://jsbin.com/weribi/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".cecutient-btn").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".more-info-open")
    .slideToggle("slow")
    .toggleClass("active");

  });

});
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: You need to use ajax

Comment: Well you cannot execute php code on click of button from the client side because jquery is client side and php is server side. You need to learn and try with ajax..http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You cannot run php from a button. You can make an Ajax call to a php page to make it run

Comment: lookup jquery ajax on the net. That should help you. Check it out here [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/]

Comment: PHP is interpreted on **your server** while `click` event is triggered on user **browser**. You should use Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Do an **ajax Call** on the **click** event

Study , and learn ! Start from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".cecutient-btn").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find(".more-info-open")
    .slideToggle("slow")
    .toggleClass("active");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "yourFile.php", //your file .php
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });

  });

});
```

An ajax call without jquery [[info here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400')
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for the OP please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run php code from a click event you'd need to do an ajax call to your php page.
php is a serverside language and can't be run on a browser.

check out the docs for jquery's ajax functions [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

you'd want something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/myPhpPage.php"
}).done(function() {
    //callback code here
});
```